# Can someone tell me what the recurrence equation for this code is?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Consider the algorithm below

Precondition: n is a non-negative integer

function f ( n )

{

temp = 0

if (n != 0)

{

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)

temp = temp + n * f(n-1)

return temp

}

else

return 1;

Solve for the closed form by repeated substitution

Comment: It's not hard to eliminate a cycle and see what the function does.

Comment: Nice question. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)